# Why is my root directory accessible from apache?

Tags: apache

I was playing around when I suddenly noticed that my browser could access my root directory just by typing "/" in the address. I checked the httpd.conf, it clearly states:

```
<Directory "/">
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

I am on Fedora 29 and this is my httpd.conf:

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

Listen 80
LimitRequestBody  5242880

Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

User apache
Group apache

ServerAdmin root@localhost

<Directory "/">
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www">
    LimitRequestBody 5242880
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html">
LimitRequestBody  5242880

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride None

    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

LogLevel warn 

<IfModule log_config_module>

    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    LimitRequestBody  5242880
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI
    Require all granted
    SetHandler fcgid-script
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>

    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types

    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>

EnableSendfile on

IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf

LimitRequestBody 1024000

<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin/data">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
    Allow From 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: You should mention to directory path inside the directory tag <Directory "/example/example/directory">

Comment: I dont get you @Creative87

Comment: No problem if you want to use directory tags right then you should know that there's different between use directory tag inside virtual host and outside if you use it inside virtual host tag then directory rules will applied to all files in this directory.      Check this tutorial for more overview     https://serversforhackers.com/c/configuring-apache-virtual-hosts

Comment: I am not using any Virtual Hosts. @Creative87

Comment: You should set virtual host and if you don't have domain name so you can set it to IP address with the port you use. Just replace domain name with your IP address. This should work. Make try.

Comment: I did this: ```<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin root@localhost
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
</VirtualHost>
``` and it made no difference @Creative87

Comment: Did you restart apache after you made this change  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192217/discussion-between-hemil-and-creative87).

Comment: @hemil you should really self-answer or delete the question, based on the chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My root directory was not accessed by apache. It was file uri parameters.